# How to position bars along side the X axis in bar3?

Tags: matlab, graph, 3d, bar-chart

I am trying to plot bars using bar3 on a background image. Although the bar3 command is able to move the bars alongside the Y-axis, I have no idea how to move the bars in the X-axis direction.

This is an example of what I use, but still cannot move the bars in the X-axis.

```
A = [10 5 20 8];
bar3(1:4, A)
xlabel('x'); ylabel('y');
```

Do you have any ideas how to move the bars to the desired position? Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "moving" the bars?

Comment: I meant to position them at a desired place along side the X-axis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify the X coordinate of your bars after they have been created and move them where ever you want them.  The example below moves the 4 bars in your example, output img shown below.

```
f = figure;
ax = axes ( 'parent', f );
A = [10 5 20 8];
h = bar3(ax, 1:4, A );
xlabel('x'); 
ylabel('y');
% create some new positions for the xdata
index = randperm(4);
% the xdata is blocks on 6x4 coordinates
start = 1;
for ii=1:4
  finish = start+5;
  % for each block of data update the x co-ordinate
  %   this will "move" if along the x-axis
  h.XData(start:finish,:)=h.XData(start:finish,:)+index(ii);
  start = finish+1;
end
% Update the xlim of the axes to display them
ax.XLim = [0 5];
```

[image: updated bar positions]